# Display name instead of id. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables; Students and Grade. Students contains foreign key grade_id referencing Grade.
For viewing students, I have used following code;
Controller:

```
public function viewStudent()
    {

       $students=Student::all();
        return $students('grade_id');
        $grade = Grade::find($id, ['id', 'grade_name']);

        return view('students.view',compact('students'));
    }
```

View:

```
 <tbody>
            @foreach($students as $student)
            <tr class="info">
                <td>{{$student->first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->middle_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->grade_id}}</td>


            </tr>

            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

Model:

```
class student extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['first_name','middle_name','last_name','grade_id'];
}
```

It shows grade_id as i have called it. But I want grade_name instead of that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define a relation to `Grade` in your student model:

```
class student extends Model
{
  public function grade() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class);
  }
}
```

Then you should be able to eagerly load grades for students with

```
$students = Student::with('grade')->get();
```

and access student's grade name with

```
$student->grade->name
```

Answer (score 1):

In Model

```
class student extends Model
{

protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'grade_id'];

  public function grade()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('Grade');
  }
}
```

In Controller

```
$students = Student::with('grade')->get();
```

In View

```
@foreach ($students as $student)
    $studentGradeName = $student->grade->name;
@endforeach
```